# State stop working as soon as i add ng-controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I am trying to add a controller to this state but as soon as i add the "ng-controller" attribute, this state stops working. I need to login a user as soon as it is authorized through firebase but i am unable to do so because of this issue. Have already initialized the app with ng-app.

```
<!--Sign In-->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="signin.html">
      <ion-view view-title="Sign In">
        <ion-content ng-controller="loginCtrl">
          <form name="login" novalidate>
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
              <span class="input-label">Email</span>
              <input type="email" placeholder="xyz@something.com" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-minlength="5" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
              <span class="input-label">Password</span>
              <input type="password" placeholder="******" name="pass" ng-model="pass" ng-minlength="6" required>
            </label>
          </div>
           <div class="padding">
            <p ng-show="login.email.$error.required && login.email.$dirty && login.email.$touched">*Email is required</p>
            <p ng-show="login.email.$invalid && !login.email.$pristine">*Email not valid</p>
            <p ng-show="login.pass.$error.required && login.pass.$dirty && login.pass.$touched">*Password is required</p>
            <p ng-show="login.pass.$error.minlength">*Password must be longer than 6 characters</p>
          </div>
          <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-block button-royal" ng-disabled="login.$invalid">Sign In</button>
          </div>
         </form>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    <!--End Sign In-->
```

And this is the js code for states

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  //main route
  $stateProvider.state("main",{
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "main.html"
  });

  //signin route
  $stateProvider.state("signin",{
    url: "/signin",
    templateUrl: "signin.html",
    controller: "loginCtrl"
  });

 //signup route
  $stateProvider.state("signup",{
    url: "/signup",
    templateUrl: "signup.html"
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
})
```

Comment: It looks like you are declaring 2 times the same controller for the same view: one in the route config, one on the HTML.

Comment: i tried declaring controller separately on both app.js and html. Still didnt work. It starts to behave strangely. If i go to signup route and return, it opens up the signin route.

Answer (score 0):

Controller has to be declared once and it would be cleaner to declare in the config function.So remove ng-controller="loginCtrl" from signin.html

Comment: I did. Still the same issue. The behavior becomes strange. It does not open when i click the button but when i go to some other state, it opens along with it